# IOS XIB storyboard Launch Screen file displays wrong orientation of an image inside

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, orientation

I am using js based app with the support of ejecta kitchen. My problem is an image which i have set on the MainWindow that displays wrong orientation or in other words it displays fixed orientation. My application require everything to  be displays in landscape mode but XIB file display things upside down whenever i change the orientation of my IPAD.

I have searched alot on internet but i could not find any possible solution yet.This is the only file which has this problem , other than this my index.html file works fine which is built on construct2.

Here is the image which displays the hierarchy of my window and image

[image]

Comment: Hey wolvorinePk, for above problem you need to rotate your image in respect to window because UIWindow will always give single orientation and that is portrait.

Comment: I did and it worked but suppose if user rotate his ipad right after this screen then the picture orientation displays as upside down, it seems like it automatically fixed the orientation. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Yes for that you need to rotate your image again in appDelegate method "willChangeStatusBarOrientation" or "didChangeStatusBarOrientation".

Comment: could you show any example and in which file i need to do that? I am novice in xcode and this is my first project and my files were generated by construct2 and ejecta kitchen. So i am very new in this domain.

Comment: I run into the same issue and looking for a solution. The solution below will not work because the app is not launched yet when iOS display your Launch XIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your issue, you can write your code as below in `AppDelegate` method.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation
        duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (newStatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        yourImage.transform      = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    else if (newStatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        yourImage.transform      = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(newStatusBarOrientation))
    {
        float rotate    = ((newStatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ? -1:1) * (M_PI / 2.0);
        yourImage.transform      = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotate);
        yourImage.transform      = CGAffineTransformTranslate(yourImage.transform, 0, -yourImage.frame.origin.y);
    }
}
```

as per the above code, you can rotate your Background image.

Comment: I have tried using above code and i have declare the UIImage like UIImage *yourname = [UIImage ImageNamed:@"mypicture.png"] , but it gives error that property 'transform' not found on object of type UIImage???

Comment: okay i have declare the imageview as yourImage and initialize the image inside. But still when i run the application it displays in wrong orientation. My XIB MainWindow is like splash screen it should be display for few seconds and then it should run index.js file for html5 game. Do you think the above method is not working due to any of my above mention things?

Comment: as per you mention that you are using html5 for further process but it will not affect in any of native code have you debug your code ?

try to debug your code with provided method.

if this method is not calling at change orientation time than your app only support single orientation.

or if this method call than check whether this if-else condition satisfy or not.